# Hardhat: InvalidInputError: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx

Tags: gas, hardhat, test

I am getting following error:

`InvalidInputError: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The max upfront cost is: 1720878550726790368 and the sender's account only has: 47925025381294726`

I am writing a test script by forking the mainnet.
On running the following code, I am getting the error.

It is a code to change a string, there is a function on the smart contract to change the global string variable and for that, I wrote the following test.

```
    let A, a;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        A = await ethers.getContractFactory("A");
        a = await A.deploy();
        await a.deployed();
    });



            it('Changing String', async function () {
                await hre.network.provider.request({
                    method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
                    params: ["0xaccount"],
                });
                const signer = await ethers.getSigner("0xaccount");
                const a_test = a.connect(signer);
                await a_test.setString('hi');
            });
```

`InvalidInputError: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The max upfront cost is: 1606289727240871152 and the sender's account only has: 95025779957785787`

My Config file, if that will help:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: "https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/N***********",
        blockNumber: 13060982
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend trying these:**

1. Set `gas` to `auto` in hardhat config [read more here](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/2159)
2. Set `gas` to `2100000` or lower in the hardhat config as it defaults to the way too high `blockGasLimit`(`30000000`). [This value is not applied if you are using](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#gas) **`ethers`**, which you do.
3. If you are using **`ethers`**, you'll need to manually set the gas override in the relevant transactions.
4. Alternatively, setting a low base fee per gas with `initialBaseFeePerGas` could help too - the default is `1000000000`.
5. Increase default account balance to a higher value [in the config](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#accounts) (from `10000` to `1000000` ETH)